# Is there an application scope variable feature in PHP?

Tags: php

I wish to store a variable to be accessible by all sessions, similar to the idea of "application object" in ASP. Is this feature supported by PHP?

Comment: Are you referring to global $var that you can use in other files?

Comment: Have you considered [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)? It's stored on the client's computer and a simple `isset($_COOKIE["var"])` could do the trick.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - there isn`t. Try using a database or serialize the information into a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the original architecture of PHP is based on CGI, inherently, no. There might be something in container-based PHP's, but I don't believe there's anything in the API.

That being said, there's support for global caches, which run in a process outside of PHP.

What are you trying to accomplish? Generally, trying to do a straight translation of ASP code to PHP won't get you far - same for changing from any one language/platform to another - you have to free your mind and learn to think the way of the platform you're learning.

Comment: thank you for the recommendations. I was trying to create an application cache using PHP, guess I will have to seek alternative solution.

Comment: Ah, then yes - there are caches for PHP. The most common one is memcached, which is a cache in general, and an API is available for it in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to store a variable between page requests, but not grouped by session but global across all users?

Why not just write it to a file?

```
// Read
$variable = unserialize(file_get_contents('/path/to/applicationVariable.txt'));

// Write
file_put_contents('/path/to/applicationVariable.txt', serialize($variable));
```

(Note: of course, the filesystem isn't the best place for these. A database or cache server might be better suited, depending on what it's for.)